# Regarding moving createtestdata method to @testsetup

Tags: apex, unit-test

I created a method `Createtestdata` which is called in all the methods in `testclass`, So when i am trying to move this `Createtestdata` method to `@testSetup` as the salesforce best practice to move common methods to `@testsetup` but My test class is failing can you please suggest what should i do.

```
@isTest
private class MS_LFOPSSendToAwd_Test {

    private static Case testCase;
    private static final String CASE_RECORD_TYPE_CASE_EXP_CLAIMS = 'Claims - Express';
    private static final String exp_claim_recordTypeId = Util.getCaseRecordTypeId(CASE_RECORD_TYPE_CASE_EXP_CLAIMS);

    //Test data creation for this class
    @testSetup static void createTestingData(){
        User testUser = TestUtility.createUser(Constants.INTEGRATION_USER, true);
        List<CaseTypeToWorkTypeListSetting__c> settings=new List<CaseTypeToWorkTypeListSetting__c>();
        CaseTypeToWorkTypeListSetting__c setting = new CaseTypeToWorkTypeListSetting__c();
        setting.Name = 'Inforce Illustration';
        setting.LFOPS_AWD_Work_Item_Type__c = 'INFILLUST';
        setting.LFOPS_Case_Record_Type__c = 'Inforce Illustration';
        settings.add(setting);        
        CaseTypeToWorkTypeListSetting__c setting1 = new CaseTypeToWorkTypeListSetting__c();
        setting1.Name = 'Death Claim Notification';
        setting1.LFOPS_AWD_Work_Item_Type__c = 'DEATHCLM';
        setting1.LFOPS_Case_Record_Type__c = 'Claims';
        settings.add(setting1); 
        insert settings;
        TestUtility.createValidationWorkflowBypassSettingTest(); 
    }


    // Test method for Creation of Work Order Id with Microservice Successful Rest service
   static testMethod void testCreateService() {
        User testuser = [Select Id from User where Profile.Name =:Constants.INTEGRATION_USER and Test_Class_User__c = true and isactive = true Limit 1];
        system.runAs(testUser){
            Util.executeMicroserviceCod=(Generic_Configuration_Reference__mdt) JSON.deserialize( '{"Boolean_Criteria__c":true}', Generic_Configuration_Reference__mdt.class );

            createCaseTestData();   
            testCase.RecordTypeId = Constants.CS_RT_INFORCE_ILLUSTRATION;
            insert testCase;
            Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MS_LFOPSSendToAWD_Create_Update_Mock('Success','Create'));
            Test.startTest(); 
            testCase.Status = Constants.CASE_STATUS_COMPLETED;
            testCase.Create_AWD_Work_Item__c = true;           
            CaseTriggerHandler.prevCaseId=null;
            update testCase;
            Test.stopTest();
            Case cs=[Select Id,AWD_Work_Item_ID__c from Case where Id=:testCase.Id LIMIT 1];

            System.assert(cs.AWD_Work_Item_ID__c!=null);
        }

    }

    static testMethod void testCaseCommentCreateService() {
        User testuser = [Select Id from User where Profile.Name =:Constants.INTEGRATION_USER and Test_Class_User__c = true and isactive = true Limit 1];
        system.runAs(testUser){
            createCaseTestData();   
            testCase.RecordTypeId = Constants.CS_RT_INFORCE_ILLUSTRATION;

            insert testCase;
             CaseComment cc = TestUtility.createCaseComment(testCase.Id, 'Testing case to AWD work item update', true);            
             testCase.AWD_Work_Item_ID__c='2019-08-06-19.31.28.926760C01';
            update testCase;
           MS_LFOPSSendToAwd.testClassSkip=true;
            Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MS_LFOPSSendToAWD_Create_Update_Mock('Success','Create'));
            Test.startTest(); 
    Datetime scTime = system.now().addSeconds(60);
        String day = string.valueOf(scTime.day());
        String month = string.valueOf(scTime.month());
        String hour = string.valueOf(scTime.hour());
        String minute = string.valueOf(scTime.minute());
        String second = string.valueOf(scTime.second());
        String year = string.valueOf(scTime.year());
       Integer randomNo = (Integer)(Math.random() * 100);

        String strJobName = 'CaseCommentsPush-' + second + '_' + minute + '_' + hour + '_' + day + '_' + month + '_' + year + '_' + randomNo;
        String strSchedule = second + ' ' + minute + ' ' + hour + ' ' + day + ' ' + month + ' ?' + ' ' + year;


        System.schedule(strJobName.trim(), strSchedule, new SendCaseCommentsToAWDBatch(testCase.Id));
            Test.stopTest();
        }

    }
    // Test method for Creation of Work Order Id with Microservice Successful Rest service :: Record Type Claims - Express

    static testMethod void testCreateServiceForExpClaims() {
        User testuser = [Select Id from User where Profile.Name =:Constants.INTEGRATION_USER and Test_Class_User__c = true and isactive = true Limit 1];
        system.runAs(testUser){
            createCaseTestData();
            testCase.RecordTypeId = exp_claim_recordTypeId;
            testCase.LFOPS_Disclosure_Statement_1_Response__c=true;
            testCase.LFOPS_Disclosure_Statement_1_Response__c=true;
            insert testCase;
            Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MS_LFOPSSendToAWD_Create_Update_Mock('Success','Create'));
            Test.startTest(); 
            testCase.Status = Constants.CASE_STATUS_COMPLETED;
            testCase.Create_AWD_Work_Item__c = true;           
            CaseTriggerHandler.prevCaseId=null;
            update testCase;
            Test.stopTest();
            Case cs=[Select Id,AWD_Work_Item_ID__c from Case where Id=:testCase.Id LIMIT 1];

            System.assert(cs.AWD_Work_Item_ID__c!=null);
        }


    }
    // Test method for Creation of Work Order Id with Microservice Successful Rest service :: Case Origin ORIGIN_FORMS_PORTAL

    static testMethod void testCreateServiceCaseOriginPortal() {
        User testuser = [Select Id from User where Profile.Name =:Constants.INTEGRATION_USER and Test_Class_User__c = true and isactive = true Limit 1];
        system.runAs(testUser){
            createCaseTestData();
            testCase.RecordTypeId = exp_claim_recordTypeId;
            testCase.LFOPS_Disclosure_Statement_1_Response__c=true;
            testCase.LFOPS_Disclosure_Statement_1_Response__c=true;
            testCase.Origin = constants.ORIGIN_FORMS_PORTAL;
            insert testCase;
            Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MS_LFOPSSendToAWD_Create_Update_Mock('Success','Create'));
            Test.startTest(); 
            testCase.Status = Constants.CASE_STATUS_COMPLETED;
            testCase.Create_AWD_Work_Item__c = true;           
            CaseTriggerHandler.prevCaseId=null;
            update testCase;
            Test.stopTest();
            Case cs=[Select Id,AWD_Work_Item_ID__c from Case where Id=:testCase.Id LIMIT 1];
            System.assert(cs.AWD_Work_Item_ID__c!=null);
        }


    }
    //  Test method for Creation of Work Order Id with Microservice Failure Rest service 

    static testMethod void testwithoutresponse() {
        User testuser = [Select Id from User where Profile.Name =:Constants.INTEGRATION_USER and Test_Class_User__c = true and isactive = true Limit 1];
        system.runAs(testUser){ 
            createCaseTestData();
            testCase.RecordTypeId = Constants.CS_RT_INFORCE_ILLUSTRATION;
            insert testCase;
            Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MS_LFOPSSendToAWD_Create_Update_Mock('Failure','Create'));
            Test.startTest(); 
            testCase.Status = Constants.CASE_STATUS_COMPLETED;
            testCase.Create_AWD_Work_Item__c = true;           
            CaseTriggerHandler.prevCaseId=null;
            update testCase;
            Test.stopTest();
            Case cs=[Select Id,AWD_Work_Item_ID__c,AWD_Work_Item_Status__c from Case where Id=:testCase.Id LIMIT 1];
            System.assertEquals(System.Label.Case_AWD_Work_Item_Status_Error,cs.AWD_Work_Item_Status__c);

        }
    }
     // Test method for Invalid work Type

    static testMethod void testForNoWorkType() {
        User testuser = [Select Id from User where Profile.Name =:Constants.INTEGRATION_USER and Test_Class_User__c = true and isactive = true Limit 1];
        system.runAs(testUser){ 
            createCaseTestData();
            testCase.RecordTypeId = Util.getCaseRecordTypeId('Titles');
            insert testCase;
            Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MS_LFOPSSendToAWD_Create_Update_Mock('Failure','Create'));
            Test.startTest(); 
            testCase.Status = Constants.CASE_STATUS_COMPLETED;
            testCase.Create_AWD_Work_Item__c = true;           
            CaseTriggerHandler.prevCaseId=null;
            update testCase;
            Test.stopTest();
            Case cs=[Select Id,AWD_Work_Item_ID__c,AWD_Work_Item_Status__c from Case where Id=:testCase.Id LIMIT 1];
            System.assertEquals(System.Label.Case_AWD_Work_Item_Status_Error,cs.AWD_Work_Item_Status__c);

        }
    }
     // Test method for Successful Microservice Rest service On Case Expedite
    static testMethod void testUpdateService() {
        User testuser = [Select Id from User where Profile.Name =:Constants.INTEGRATION_USER and Test_Class_User__c = true and isactive = true Limit 1];
        system.runAs(testUser){
            createCaseTestData();   
            testCase.RecordTypeId = Constants.CS_RT_INFORCE_ILLUSTRATION;
            insert testCase;
            Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MS_LFOPSSendToAWD_Create_Update_Mock('Success','Update'));
            Test.startTest(); 
            testCase.Status = Constants.CASE_STATUS_COMPLETED;
            testCase.Create_AWD_Work_Item__c = true;           
            CaseTriggerHandler.prevCaseId=null;
            testCase.AWD_Work_Item_ID__c='2019-08-06-19.31.28.926760C01';
            testCase.Expedite__c=true;
            update testCase;
            Test.stopTest();
             List<Error_Log__c> erorLogList=[Select Id from Error_Log__c];
            System.assert(erorLogList.isEmpty());
        }

    }
    // Test method for Successful Microservice Rest service On Case Comment 

    static testMethod void testCaseCommentService() {
        User testuser = [Select Id from User where Profile.Name =:Constants.INTEGRATION_USER and Test_Class_User__c = true and isactive = true Limit 1];
        system.runAs(testUser){
            createCaseTestData();   
            testCase.RecordTypeId = Constants.CS_RT_INFORCE_ILLUSTRATION;
            testCase.Status = Constants.CASE_STATUS_COMPLETED;
            testCase.Create_AWD_Work_Item__c = true;           
            testCase.AWD_Work_Item_ID__c='2019-08-06-19.31.28.926760C01';
            insert testCase;
            Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MS_LFOPSSendToAWD_Create_Update_Mock('Success','Update'));
            Test.startTest(); 
            CaseComment cc = TestUtility.createCaseComment(testCase.Id , 'Test Comment', true);
            Test.stopTest();
             List<Error_Log__c> erorLogList=[Select Id from Error_Log__c];
            System.assert(erorLogList.isEmpty());
        }
    }
    // Test method for Failure Microservice Rest service On Case Expedite

    static testMethod void testUpdateServiceFailure() {
        User testuser = [Select Id from User where Profile.Name =:Constants.INTEGRATION_USER and Test_Class_User__c = true and isactive = true Limit 1];
        system.runAs(testUser){
            createCaseTestData();   
            testCase.RecordTypeId = Constants.CS_RT_INFORCE_ILLUSTRATION;
            insert testCase;
            Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MS_LFOPSSendToAWD_Create_Update_Mock('Failure','Update'));
            Test.startTest(); 
            testCase.Status = Constants.CASE_STATUS_COMPLETED;
            testCase.Create_AWD_Work_Item__c = true;           
            CaseTriggerHandler.prevCaseId=null;
            testCase.AWD_Work_Item_ID__c='2019-08-06-19.31.28.926760C01';
            testCase.Expedite__c=true;
            update testCase;
            Test.stopTest();
             List<Error_Log__c> erorLogList=[Select Id from Error_Log__c];
            System.assert(!erorLogList.isEmpty());
        }

    }
     static testMethod void testUpdateServiceLogErrorFailure() {
        User testuser = [Select Id from User where Profile.Name =:Constants.INTEGRATION_USER and Test_Class_User__c = true and isactive = true Limit 1];
        system.runAs(testUser){
            createCaseTestData();   
            testCase.RecordTypeId = Constants.CS_RT_INFORCE_ILLUSTRATION;
            insert testCase;
            Test.startTest(); 
            testCase.Status = Constants.CASE_STATUS_COMPLETED;
            testCase.Create_AWD_Work_Item__c = true;           
            CaseTriggerHandler.prevCaseId=null;
            testCase.AWD_Work_Item_ID__c='2019-08-06-19.31.28.926760C01';
            testCase.Expedite__c=true;
            update testCase;
            Test.stopTest();
             List<Error_Log__c> erorLogList=[Select Id from Error_Log__c];
            System.assert(!erorLogList.isEmpty());
        }

    }
    // Test method for Failure Microservice Rest service On Case Expedite

    static testMethod void testCaseCommentServiceFailure() {
        User testuser = [Select Id from User where Profile.Name =:Constants.INTEGRATION_USER and Test_Class_User__c = true and isactive = true Limit 1];
        system.runAs(testUser){
            createCaseTestData();   
            testCase.RecordTypeId = Constants.CS_RT_INFORCE_ILLUSTRATION;
            testCase.Status = Constants.CASE_STATUS_COMPLETED;
            testCase.Create_AWD_Work_Item__c = true;           
            testCase.AWD_Work_Item_ID__c='2019-08-06-19.31.28.926760C01';
            insert testCase;
            Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MS_LFOPSSendToAWD_Create_Update_Mock('Failure','Update'));
            Test.startTest(); 
            CaseComment cc = TestUtility.createCaseComment(testCase.Id , 'Test Comment', true);
            Test.stopTest();
             List<Error_Log__c> erorLogList=[Select Id from Error_Log__c];
            System.assert(!erorLogList.isEmpty());
        }
    }
     static testMethod void testCaseCommentServiceLogErrorFailure() {
        User testuser = [Select Id from User where Profile.Name =:Constants.INTEGRATION_USER and Test_Class_User__c = true and isactive = true Limit 1];
        system.runAs(testUser){
            createCaseTestData();   
            testCase.RecordTypeId = Constants.CS_RT_INFORCE_ILLUSTRATION;
            testCase.Status = Constants.CASE_STATUS_COMPLETED;
            testCase.Create_AWD_Work_Item__c = true;           
            testCase.AWD_Work_Item_ID__c='2019-08-06-19.31.28.926760C01';
            insert testCase;
            Test.startTest(); 
            CaseComment cc = TestUtility.createCaseComment(testCase.Id , 'Test Comment', true);

            Test.stopTest();
             List<Error_Log__c> erorLogList=[Select Id from Error_Log__c];
            System.assert(!erorLogList.isEmpty());
        }
    }

    //Case Creation
    private static void createCaseTestData() {      
        Account account = TestUtility.createAccount(true);
        Contact contact = TestUtility.createContact(account.Id, true);
        Account PA = TestUtility.createPersonAccount(true);
        Policy_Contract__c policy = TestUtility.createPolicyContract('P-0001', true);
        Policy_Role__c PR = TestUtility.createPolicyRole(PA.Id, policy.Id, true);
        testCase = TestUtility.createCase(account.Id, contact.Id, 'Inforce Illustration', 'Test', false);   
        testCase.Effective_Date__c = Date.today();
        testCase.Case_Due_Date__c = date.today().addDays(5);
        testCase.Policy_Contract__c = policy.Id;
        testCase.Caller_Type__c = 'Insured';
        testCase.Date_of_Death__c = date.today().addDays(-5);
        testCase.State__c='Oregon';
        testCase.LFOPS_Policy_Issue_Date__c=System.today();
        testCase.LFOPS_Insured_Date_of_Birth__c=System.today();
        testCase.LFOPS_Beneficiary_Date_of_Birth__c=System.today();
        testCase.LFOPS_Disclosure_Statement_2_Response__c=true;
        testCase.LFOPS_Cause_of_Death__c='Infection';
        testCase.LFOPS_Specific_Cause__c='Influenza';

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error you are getting ? Can you also post the stack trace and the relevant code?

Comment: My test class is failing. if createtestdata is separate method then code coverage is 99%. but when i am moving it to @testsetup all the methods are failing

Comment: We'll need to see your code if you hope to get an accurate answer. You should [edit] your question to include it. My shot-in-the-dark guess is that you're relying on static variables (which are reset before running each test method).

Comment: @Akhilesh you will have to provide the error that you are getting so that community can help you fix that. Just mentioning "failing" in the question will not help.

Comment: Added the complete code here, All i need is move the createtestdata to @testsetup

Answer (score 2):

You would need to re-query your test data as opposed to just accessing the variables from the method as you don't have access to them from TestSetup. If you see the example linked below for TestSetup, you'll see they requery the test account data in each test method after the testSetup creates it. The test setup re-runs before every test method.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_testsetup_using.htm

Comment: Thanks for the advise. Will that change the code coverage as of now the code coverage is 99%

Comment: Is it a good practice to move transnational data to @testsetup?

Comment: No. The querying would be a change done in the test methods. Your actual code that is being covered by these tests will still be covered as you're still executing the same logic in the test class.

Comment: just saw your other comment. It is recommended to use testSetup how you would be using it in your situation. To create the data needed to run the logic in the tests. You also have the option to only query whatever data is needed for the asserts as opposed to always re-querying all test data you created in every single method.

Comment: Thanks very much.

Comment: But is it good practice to move transaction data to testsetup?